# Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, xampp, wamp

[image]

I am using codeigniter 3.0.6 on XAMPP 7.0.8 with PHP 7.0.8 and Apache 2.4.6. I kept getting this error every time there was a load on the site. So basically, there are 3 users on three different machines with three different logins repeatedly opening tabs and navigating on the site it causes the site to crash and show this error.

I tried changing to WAMP64, Apache 2.4.27, PHP 7.0.23 but unfortunately I still get this error.

Is there a way to fix this or any clue what might be the problem?

When I was using PHP 5.6 on XAMP 1.8 I never had this problem now I am being forced to downgrade the software and my code back to this version of xampp and php.

I have not changed any of the system files for codeigniter. Turning of XAMPP or WAMP fixes it but then if there is a load again it crashes and shows same message.

Comment: @paolo I have seen this before... Restarting Xampp or Wamp fixes it but then after trying to hammer the system again it crashes.. I have not modified the system folder or any files.

Comment: @Narf thanks for reply I have seen this question and made sure that opcache.enable=0 but still problem occurs.

Comment: @MohamedMahyoub If you actually read the entire thing, you'll know that there's no solution - it's a PHP 7 bug with mod_php on Windows.